# Change Class of UL list menu which has submenus using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a horizontal menu which has sub-menu's also i only want to change the background color on hover effect of parent menu if it has submenu.

like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Yz/11/

In above example i am hard-coding the `has-submenu` to get the desired effect but problem is that my actual menu is dynamically generated from database & so far i have not been able to figure out a way to assign `has-submenu` class from code itself to make it work.

So that solution i am looking for is to use add new CSS class using jquery to only those elements which have submenu's.

I am not sure how i can find this element 
`<li><span class="dir"><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span>`

and change class using jQuery from `dir` to `has-submenu`
`<li><span class="has-submenu"><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span>`

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Yz/10/) link has the actual code which i want to change  to get the desired result as show in the link example above.

http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Yz/10/

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="dropdown dropdown-linear" id="nav">
        <li class="active"><span class="dir"><a href="#">HOME</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
        <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
        <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">ARTICLES</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
        <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">CATEGORIES</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Politics</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feature</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Economy</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feature</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Business</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">ARCHIVE</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">2013</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">2012</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">2011</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">2010</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">2009</a><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="dir"><a href="#">NEWS</a></span><span id="menus-spacer">|</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ukd/)

```
$(function () {
     $('#nav > li').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
        if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
            $(this).find('.dir').toggleClass('has-submenu');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This Works I will fix the CSS to make it look Pretty.

Comment: Great.. Glad to know... :)

Comment: I Just noticed problem with this function that it it works only when one hover over the parent menu, Moment i move my cursor down to sub-menu it then changes the background to white how can i keep the backgroud-color even when i am on submenu

Comment: Managed to make it work by adding CSS `.has-submenu
{
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way, the document ready function it's wrapped in just tells jQuery to do it right when the page is finished loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#nav-wrapper ul li span").removeClass("dir").addClass("has-submenu");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Yz/16/

jQuery uses the same method as css to select an element, so #nav-wrapper ul li span would work the same as a css selector also, to target any spans inside of an li inside of a ul inside the #nav-wrapper:

```
#nav-wrapper ul li span{
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav li").each(function() {
    if($(this) .has('ul')) {
      $(this).addClass('has-submenu');   
    }
    });  
});
```

Or if you want to by php then you have to show your php code which generates menus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.dropdown > li').hover(function(){
        if($(this).find('ul'))
        {
            $(this).find('ul').addClass('sub-menu');                
        }
    },function(){
        if($(this).find('ul'))
        {
            $(this).find('ul').removeClass('sub-menu');                
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YA2Yz/17/